# Verifying access token from Google using spring security

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect, google-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate API-calls with my spring-boot backend by giving it an access token that I've gotten from Google.

From what I understand of the documentation it should be enough to just declare

```
security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

in the `application.properties` file along with enabling resource server and web security.

The token is being sent in in the header on the form

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.ImCQBz5-600zVNsB[...]ka-x5kC[...]hvw-BGf3m5Bck-HF[...]44'
```

When I try to authenticate I get a 401 Unauthorized error with the following console error:

```
OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter: Authentication request failed: error="invalid_token", error_description="An I/O error occurred while reading the JWT: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xad at [Source: (byte[])"??"; line: 1, column: 3]
```

I'm hoping to use most of what I can of the spring security libraries, but I've tried to write my own simple beans for token management.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new jwkTokenStore("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
    @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices());
    }
}
```

I expect to authenticate the token and be able to display information.

Do I need to write my own functions to handle this?

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?
I have a similar problem. I use both `security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri` and `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri` the problem that I have is that the request that calls for jwk on configuration is sending a request and the data is not able to be resolved. (there is no 'value' prop).

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. I was able to solve it following this blog-post: https://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/google-oauth-with-spring-security-as-separated-resource-server/
I ended up continuing down this path however as we're working on a in-house solution similar to this: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you must implement the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class RestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AADAppRoleStatelessAuthenticationFilter appRoleAuthFilter;

    private final RestAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    private final RestAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/refresh").hasRole("Admin")
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(appRoleAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler);

    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
It turns out that you need to import specific jwt dependencies, the default oauth2 dependencies will not work with key-set-uri.

My dependecies that I use:

```
        'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security',

        'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose',
        'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server',
```

The second one is the most important. 
Now, you will have the `JwtDecoder` and `NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport` on your classpath you can configure SpringBoot.
This is my setup :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
  private String issuer;

  @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
  private String jwkSetUri;

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()

        ...

        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
        .decoder(decoder());
  }

  private JwtDecoder decoder() {
    List<OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt>> validators = new ArrayList<>();
    validators.add(new JwtTimestampValidator());
    validators.add(new JwtIssuerValidator(issuer));
    validators.add(new TokenSupplierValidator(List.of(StringUtils.split(androidClientId,","))));

    NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport decoder = new NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport(jwkSetUri)
    decoder.setJwtValidator(new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(validators));
    return decoder;
  }
}
```

If you need only default JWT token validation, you can go with the default validation (no need for setting up the custom validator).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something very similar to this that worked.

Comment: @Hagen please, tell us what you did